# Complex Solution

Tags: complex-numbers

I was looking at a simple complex problem and I came by this:

Solve: $z^2 = 3 - 4i$

Let
$$z= x + yi$$
Rewrite as
$$(x + yi)^2 = 3 - 4i$$
Expand
$$x^2 +2xyi + y^2i^2 = 3 - 4i$$
Simplify
$$x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi = 3 - 4i$$
real/imaginary parts
$$x^2 - y^2 = 3$$

and

$$2xy = -4$$
$$xy = -2$$
Therefore $y = -\frac{2}{x}$.

Substitute $y = -\frac 2x$ into $x^2 - y^2 = 3$, giving
$$x^2 - \frac{4}{x^2} = 3$$
Multiply by $x^2$:
$x^4 - 4 = 3x^2$
Factor

$$x^4 - 3x^2 - 4 = 0$$
$$(x^2 + 1) (x^2 - 4) = 0$$
$$(x^2+ 1) (x + 2) (x - 2) = 0$$
Given $xy = -2$

for $x = 2$ then $y = -1$ therefore $z = 2 - i$

for $x = -2$ then $y = 1$ therefore $z = -2 + i$

Now, I understand everything, but why do we ignore the root of $i$ and $-i$ for the root $x^2+1=0$? Is it because we are only looking for real roots? When plugging these two back into $(x+iy)=z$, I saw that it gave the same two solutions as the real roots.

Comment: Your decision to use $ \ z \ = \ x \ + \ yi \ $ implicitly requires that $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ are real.  So you can disregard the factor $ \ x^2 \ + \ 1 \ $ in your solution of the quartic equation.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner That is what my first guess was at why we ignore it. Thank you, is it just a coincidence that they give the same answer?

Comment: When we say: let $z=x+yi$ we are *implicitly* saying that both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

Comment: "Requires" in the sense that the numbers we use in the real and imaginary parts of a complex number are real.

Comment: It is not a **coincidence** that you end up with the same answer. If you originally assumed that both $x$ and $y$ can be real or imaginary numbers when you say: let $z=x+yi$ then you would need to consider those as well - but they will indeed always lead to the same solution. It is just that you will be uncessarily doing extra computation to get to the same results.

Comment: I am curious as to why they will lead to the same answers. Can you explain it briefly or is it lengthy?

Comment: I believe the redundancy comes from inserting $ \ \pm i \ $ into your expression for $ \ z \ $ .  Since those are actually the imaginary parts [ $ \ yi \ $ ] of your solutions for $ \ z \ $ , the remainder of the calculation is now going to give you the real parts.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow.

Comment: There are only two complex square-roots for any complex number.  If we limit ourselves to using $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ real, then the factor $ \ x^2 \ + \ 1 \ $ has no real zeroes and would be neglected in the equation $ \ (x^2+ 1) (x + 2) (x - 2) = 0 \ $ ; you already have the two possible values of $ \ x \ $ for the two possible complex square-roots from the other factors.  When you inserted $ \ \pm i \ $ into the quartic equation, you are then declaring $ \ x \ $ to be imaginary and you are already using the values from the two possible complex square-roots.  (continued)

Comment: This now also inserts $ \ x \ = \ \pm i \ $ into the two factors $ \ ( x + 2 ) \ $ and $ \ ( x - 2 ) \ $ , which are certainly _not_ going to equal zero.  So those do not produce any additional solutions. Your quartic equation thus only gives either (real) $ \ x \ = \ \pm 2 \ $ or (imaginary) $ \ iy \ = \ \pm 1 \cdot i \ $ .  You then return to your "constraint" $ \ xy \ = \ -2 \ $ to obtain the other part of your two complex square-roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you said let:$$z=x+yi$$but you assumed $x$ and $y$ themselves could also be complex numbers. Then, in effect, you are stating that:$$x=a+bi$$$$y=c+di$$where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are real numbers. This effectively means that you are saying:$$z=(a+bi)+(c+di)i=(a-d)+(b+c)i$$so you will be computing these extra components: $a,b,c$ and $d$ unnecessarily to get back to the same result.

You might as well here say that let:$$u=a-d$$$$v=b+c$$so that:$$z=u+vi$$ and solve for the real numbers $u$ and $v$.

Comment: So is it safe to say that we can always circumvent this extra process by assuming $x$ and $y$ are real numbers while still obtaining the right solution to the complex equation?

Comment: Yes - in general when we state $z=x+yi$ we *implicitly* assume that both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. That is how we **define** a complex number - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Answer (score 1):

When you write $z=x+yi$ you are looking for real $x$ and $y$.

There's really nothing bad in considering also the other two possibilities, but they will give just the same numbers.

Indeed, if you take $x=i$, you obtain, from $xy=-2$, that $y=-2/i=2i$ and so
$$
z=x+yi=i+2i^2=-2+i
$$
which has already been obtained. The other solution is obtained when you consider $x=-i$.

You *know* that the equation has at most two solutions, so when you find two of them you're done.